# Standalone function and class based function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am trying to define the function without any class. I have tried three different type of syntax for doing it. But the **second one** is giving me error. The second type of syntax is working in class.

```
function test() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>function test() is called</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

test2() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>test() is called</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

const test3 = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>const test = () is called</h3>
    </div>
  );
};

function functional() {
  return (
    <div>
      {test}
      {test2}
      {test3}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: There's a difference between `functions` and `class methods`, so the syntax will vary. `test2` would be valid as a `class method`, but invalid as a regular `function`.

Comment: Well if you're not in a `class` body or object literal, then you cannot use a method definition. The other way round, `const test3 = …` or `function` declarations are invalid inside a class or object definition.  Why would you expect this to work, and what do you expect it to do?

Comment: i was only checking the difference between these different declarations. @Bergi

Comment: `test2() { … }` simply is not a declaration.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem here is React component names must start with a capital letter.

So try as the following:

```
const Test = () => {
   return <>
       { /* your implementation */ }

       { test2() }
   <>
}
```

Also you need to define your `test2` function as:

```
const test2 = () => {
  return(
     <div><h2>test() is called</h2></div>
  )
}
```

And call as `{ test2() }` in your component.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

A part that React component names must be in PascalCase as norbitria stated the problem with your second 'function' is that it is not a function, that syntax is used inside classes for declaring methods or as a shorthand in objects for declaring functions as properties.

```js
class Foo {
  test2() { console.log('im a method')}
}

var obj = {
  test2(){ console.log('another one'); } 
}
```

You can declare functions with the `function` keyword or using `arrow function expressions`:

```js
function f1() {}
var f1 = function () {}
var f1 = () => {}
```

And in React you do not normally invoke functions to render JSX, instead use them as components:

```js
function Foo() { return <h1>hello</h1> }
function Bar() {return <Foo /> }
```